# using dot in regex in java for splitting

Tags: java, regex, split

```
    String a=new String("aader");
    String str[]=a.split(".");
    int max=str.length;
    System.out.println(max);
```

a dot (`.`) means every character.

so it should split every character of a. but `max = 0` when I run the code. Why?

Comment: [Why are you trying to split your string into an array of the individual characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Do you know about `String.toCharArray` (although that would give a different type)?

Comment: just note that the argument to `split` is the delimiter used to split, not the expression of what to split... so it is returning the empty text between each character, since each character is a delimiter; and since there is no second argument, empty strings are ignored returning the empty array. Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 2):

In regex, DOT means any character not each character. In java "|" is consider as every character. So you can try something like 
    String a = new String("aader");

```
String[] result = a.split("");
```

or

```
String[] result = a.split("|");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use split with dot `split(".")` it split in any character which mean all the characters in the string considers as a delimiter, for that you get 0.

here is how split in this case work :

```
aader
^------------------------split here, so the result is 
ader
^------------------------split here, so the result is 
der
^------------------------split here, so the result is 
der
^------------------------split here, so the result is 
er
^------------------------split here, so the result is 
r
^------------------------split here, so the result is 

^------------------------this is the final result (empty, 0 result)
```

---

to split in each character you can split with empty :

```
String[] result = a.split("");// this return [a, a, d, e, r]
int max = split.length;// the result is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `String str[]=a.split(".", -1);` to get your desired result of empty array.
If you want each of the characters in the array, try `String str[]=a.split("");`

From the [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

> `public String[] split(String regex,int limit)` Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression. The array returned by this method contains each
>   substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that
>   matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the
>   string.
>
> .............
>
> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.
>
> .............
>
> If n is **non-positive then the pattern** will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

So, effectively your split regex is producing an array of empty string and empty string is discarded. To retain them you need to pass limit as **non-positive** such as `-1`

Comment: why without -1 I cant get my desired result?

Comment: Added more details from Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

To split at a dot, just escape it (as in `\.`) but be careful that the `\` must also be escaped in java, so use `split("\\.");`.